# "anche se" seguito da condizionale

Tags: verbs, conditional-mood

Stavo cercando di decidere se questo breve estratto dal testo di una canzone relativamente recente

[ Una canzone d'amore - Max Pezzali - 1995 ]

sia grammaticalmente corretto

> ... Se solo avessi le parole
>
> te lo direi
>
> anche se mi farebbe male ...

Non mi pare che sia una frase interrogativa indiretta.
Mi chiedo invece se possa essere rilevante il fatto che il *"se"* sia preceduto da *"anche"*
e che, a orecchio, mi sembri equivalente ad un *"nonostante"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da: ([dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it](https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/lingua-e-scuola/posta-del-professore/anche-se-condizionale/))

> la locuzione congiuntivale ***anche se può reggere*** oltre al congiuntivo (Anche se rubassi non sarei il primo ladro – G. GIACOSA) e all’indicativo presente (anche se non ti scrivo, ti penso sempre) e futuro (anche se arriverai stasera, non mi troverai perché sto partendo) ***anche il condizionale.***

Comment: perfetto - molte grazie! Lo terrò ben presente.

Comment: There is a difference between *Anche se non ti scrivo, ti penso sempre.* and *Anche se rubassi, non sarei il primo ladro*. They are both correct, but the difference of meaning should be noted.